# Set default font in Outlook with an addin

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-word, outlook-addin

I am writing an Outlook addin which automatically sets the default signature:

```
Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
Word.EmailOptions oOptions;
oOptions = oWord.Application.EmailOptions;
oOptions.EmailSignature.NewMessageSignature = "Standardsignatur";
oOptions.EmailSignature.ReplyMessageSignature = "Standardsignatur";
```

I am also able to set the default font for normal text msg:

```
oOptions.PlainTextStyle.Font.Name="Arial";
oOptions.PlainTextStyle.Font.Size=40;
```

But how can I change the font of a new HTML message in this addin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
Word.EmailOptions oOptions;
oOptions.ReplyStyle.Font.Name = "Arial";
oOptions.ReplyStyle.Font.Size = 10;

oOptions.ComposeStyle.Font.Name = "Arial";
oOptions.ComposeStyle.Font.Size = 10;
```

This change the Style on every startup.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook does not expose that option for programmatic access.

Comment: Is there any other way? Group policies?